# Formulas in template to automatically adjust to size of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a template in which users can dump data into columns A, B and C.
I'd like for users to be able to have a calculation per row in column D, for example `=(A1+B1)/C1`.

Is it possible to make it so that users will not need to drag-down-copy the formula in column D to fit their data?
As in, have excel automatically copy the formula in D down to D22 if there's data in A22?

Comment: How about you make the formula standard for all rows, but display blank when there is no data?

Comment: Use an Excel table? And as above, have a formula that evaluates to "" when no data.

Comment: @Luuklag How do I make a formula standard for all rows? Is this doable without filling up my excel file all the way up to row #99999999999999 with the formula?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying you should put in a formula in column D that checks if there is data in column A for that row and return "" if there isn't.

```
IF(ISBLANK(A22),"",[your formula])
```